# jquery appendTo elements not honouring css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, appendto

In the below code, the css style "onred" is not honoured.  The css is loaded before this javascript runs ... any ideas?  The result is a standard href without the styling.

```
<script> 
    $.each(parent.j25d169030c6580e7ad7cc5d785cf5fa8.userMenu, function(name, url) {
if (name == "logout") { 
    $('<li><a id="logout" href="' + url + '" class="onred">' + name + '</a></li>').appendTo('ul#navMenu');
    } else { 
        $('<li><a href="' + url + '" class="onred">' + name + '</a></li>').appendTo('ul#navMenu');
    }                       
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector may no longer be valid.

Use an inspection tool such as Firebug to see clearly where the element resides and craft your selector to suit.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is always 'honoured'. Doesn't matter which runs first or when.

Execute the code and then inspect the new DOM elements. Is there a `class="onred"` present? If there is and it's not styled the way you want, it's your CSS that's incorrect.

Comment: onred works with other elements that aren't inserted via jquery.  i can write a href=foo class="onred" and it comes out as expected